# Receive exception when perform searching in Twython

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I've just started to use twython, but on the first example:

```
from twython import Twython
t = Twython()
t.search(q='python')
```

I received an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython-2.5.2-py2.7.egg/twython/twython.py", line 367, in search
    return self.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json', params=kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython-2.5.2-py2.7.egg/twython/twython.py", line 238, in get
    return self.request(endpoint, params=params, version=version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython-2.5.2-py2.7.egg/twython/twython.py", line 233, in request
    content = self._request(url, method=method, params=params, files=files, api_call=url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython-2.5.2-py2.7.egg/twython/twython.py", line 210, in _request
    retry_after=response.headers.get('retry-after'))
twython.twython.TwythonError: 'Bad Request: The request was invalid. An accompanying error message will explain why. This is the status code will be returned during rate limiting. -- An error occurred processing your request.'
```

Do anyone know what caused this exception?

Thanks,

L

Answer (score 1):

Unauthenticated calls to Twitter API.
Read here - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you suggest the solution as I'm pretty new to this problem.

Comment: I think I found it, thanks. According to this https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth. No authentication is required to access search API, maybe they just change recently...

Answer (score 0):

From the [core examples](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/tree/master/core_examples):

```
from twython import Twython

""" Instantiate Twython with no Authentication """
twitter = Twython()
search_results = twitter.search(q="python", rpp="50")

for tweet in search_results["results"]:
    print "Tweet from @%s Date: %s" % (tweet['from_user'].encode('utf-8'),tweet['created_at'])
    print tweet['text'].encode('utf-8'),"\n"
```

I've tried it and it works.